# Not sure whats going wrong here - I'm a beginner

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a text-based game in visual basic, using visual studios, and i'm pretty sure whats going wrong is that the data for one of my variables isn't being passed to the one of my events, so when the event executes it fills in with some 0's. I've looked around to try and find a fix but because im a beginner im not really sure what i can do to it.

EDITED : 
Heres the code

```
    Public Class Entity
        Private ename As String
        Private esymbol As Char
        Private ecolor As ConsoleColor
        Private ex As Integer
        Private ey As Integer
        Public Property name() As String
            Get
                Return ename
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                ename = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property symbol() As Char
            Get
                Return esymbol
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Char)
                esymbol = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property color() As ConsoleColor
            Get
                Return ecolor
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As ConsoleColor)
                ecolor = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property x() As Integer
            Get
                Return ex
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                ex = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property y() As Integer
            Get
                Return ey
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                ey = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Sub New(ByVal ename As String, ByVal esymbol As Char, ByVal ecolor As ConsoleColor, ByVal ex As Integer, ByVal ey As Integer)
            ename = name
            esymbol = symbol
            ecolor = color
            ex = x
            ey = y
        End Sub
    End Class

Public Class Adventurer
    Inherits Entity

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)

        MyBase.New(name, "@", ConsoleColor.Magenta, x, y)

    End Sub

End Class

Module VbQuest


    Public Sub Main()
        Console.Title = "VB Quest"
        Console.SetWindowSize(80, 35)
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to VB Quest!")
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?")
        Console.Write(">")
        Dim name As String = Console.ReadLine()
        Static player = New Adventurer(name, 1, 1)
     Console.Clear()
       DrawPlayer(player)

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
Sub DrawPlayer(ByVal player As Entity)
        Console.SetCursorPosition(player.x, player.y)
        Console.ForegroundColor = player.color
        Console.Write(player.symbol)
        Console.ResetColor()
    End Sub
    End Module
```

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hiya! Welcome to Stack Overflow - please can you post the code into your question (as formatted text rather than screenshots)? You should also remove as much irrelevant stuff as possible to form a [mcve] - you'll often solve your own problem when doing this.

Comment: As an aid in removing irrelevant stuff, properties should be auto properties unless you do something in either the getter or setter.  If you are having trouble with y=y, use me.y = y

Answer (score 0):

You have the assignment order wrong in the `Entity` constructor.
Change it to

```
Public Sub New(ByVal ename As String, ByVal esymbol As Char, ByVal ecolor As ConsoleColor, ByVal ex As Integer, ByVal ey As Integer)
    name = ename
    symbol = esymbol
    color = ecolor
    x = ex
    y = ey
End Sub
```